# New To Android Animation

Tags: android-animation

I have three images which I want to move the images from one end to the other. When the first image goes beyond the window, it should start from the left side. It should run based on a timer.

What type of animation will be a perfect choice for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If each image is in an `ImageView`, you can use a `TranslateImage` on each one that is set to repeat infinitely `(setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE), setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART))`.